# AngualrJS client error after calling resource.$save: "TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'"

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I'm working on an AngularJS application. I'm quite new to AngularJS...

Everything works correctly (loading data, saving modifications for existing records, delete). The problem is with updating the client side model with the returned JSON data from the REST service. The server side code runs correctly and the DB changes are applied.

E.g.: 
I insert new record into the client side model this way:

```
$scope.addnewpage = function ($event){
        var newItem  = new Page();
        newItem.id = '-1'; // Indicates to the REST that it's an INSERT!      
        newItem.page_name = 'New Page';
        newItem.page_title_en = 'New Page';
        newItem.page_title_hu = 'Új oldal';
        newItem.mnu_title_hu = 'Nem Page';
        newItem.mnu_title_en = 'Új oldal';
        newItem.page_text_en = '...';
        newItem.page_text_hu = '...';
        newItem.page_footer_en = '...';
        newItem.page_footer_hu = '...';
        newItem.weight = '1';

        var idx = $scope.pages.push(newItem)-1;
        $scope.pages[idx].active = true;            
    }
```

On the server side, I have a PHP REST service which differentiates if the ID field contains -1 (INSERT new) or an integer larger than 0 (UPDATE existing).

If the REST returns the new record containing the NEW id and other adjusted fields to the client in a correct JSON format, AngularJS won't understand it ant sends the above error message on the browser console.

```
"TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'"
```

My service looks like this (I tried changing isArray attributes true/false - same error):

```
AdminModule.factory('Page', function($resource) {
    return $resource(
        '../admin/itcrest.php/page/:id',
        {id : '@id'},
        {  
           'get':    {method:'GET', isArray:false},
           'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
           'save':   {method:'POST', isArray:true},
           'delete': {method:'PUT', isArray:true} 
        }
    );
});
```

The controller code snippet where I do the save is this:

```
AdminModule.controller('PagesListController',  
    function ($scope, $http, $timeout, Page, $location, MessageBus, $modal) {
    // ...
    $scope.savepage = function (item, $event){
        item.$save(item, function(responseData) {}, 
            function(error) { });
    }
    // ...
 }
```

Could anybody help me how to manage new record insertions without full page reload, and update the client with the actual data from the server? What I really would like to do is returning the real data from the REST service and update the client model record with the  new data - both when UPDATE & INSERT. If I return anything else than empty JSON, it sends the error.

Since the server side code works well and returns the correct data, I think the problem must be on the client side.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> `$scope.pages` not a array. So you got this error. You must specify that to array, then you can push any values to that.

try this way.

```
        $scope.pages=[];    
        var idx = $scope.pages.push(newItem).length-1;
        $scope.pages[idx].active = true;
```

and also see this line

> var idx = $scope.pages.push(newItem)**.length-1;**

Comment: Hi Ramesh, Thank you for your answer. I load my model from the server with this code. In Chrome debugger res is an array.:

Comment: Page.query(function(res) { $scope.pages = res; }, function(error) {});

Comment: BTW, the error comes when the server returns from the $save. If I return (in the response) an empty JSON array then no error comes, only when I return the new record. But I need to get back somehow the saved data to update the client model because I modify it on the server side.